# CodeBuild IAM Role Assume Role Leveraging terraform jsoncode

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I currently have my policy working with assume_role_policy  = <<POLICY which imports the Json inline.  I want to leverage jsonencode instead and I have written the role below with the jsonecode policy.  This fails every time which has me wondering if its the principal syntax but I can't seem to find an example running more than one service.  As far as the error goes, terraform just tells me it's an error with the resource in line one which isn't much.  Grateful for any assistance here.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "codebuild_service_role" {
  name                = "codebuildservicerole"
  assume_role_policy  = jsonencode ({
    version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Sid = ""
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = ["codebuild.amazonaws.com","codepipeline.amazonaws.com"]
        }
      },

    ]

  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple service principals are comma-delimited in the IAM schema, and not an array/list:

```
assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
  version = "2012-10-17"
  Statement = [
    {
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      Sid = ""
      Effect = "Allow"
      Principal = {
        Service = "codebuild.amazonaws.com,codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
      }
    },
  ]
})
```